# How do I add null check to data shown in my code?? Flutter Firestore Query Snapshot

Tags: flutter, dart

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          initialData: null,
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('tasks')
              // .where('date', isEqualTo: date.dateTimeSelected.toString())
              .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data!.docs.length);
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                default:
                  print(snapshot.data!.docs);
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Meetingcard(
                      id: snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()["id"],
                      title: snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()["title"],
                      description:
                          snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()["description"],
                      time: snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()["timeStart"],
                    ),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  );
                \
              }
            } else {
              return Text("No Data");
            }
          },
```

**How do i add null check in the line snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()["description"]**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM5Qe.png)

Comment: You can try this:
`snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()!["id"],`

Comment: Thank You for answering.. but it is still showing bad state error